# Customizing fuzzywuzzy string matching to edit distance <= 1

Tags: python, algorithm, fuzzy-search, fuzzywuzzy

I am new in algorithms and my question may be silly, but how can I specify the edit distance in fuzzywuzzy library? I want edit distance <= 1 between two strings.

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz


fuzz.ratio('Apple', 'Aple')
```

I tried to look at source code, but I didn't understand how to customize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you restricted in any way to use the `fuzzywuzzy` library? The `ratio` function does not have parameters to set the edit distance threshold. You could of course alter the source code, however this is something you generally avoid as it is hard to maintain (for example when `fuzzywuzzy` gets an update).

You could simply implement the `ratio` function yourself, for example based on `https://github.com/miohtama/python-Levenshtein` or `https://github.com/aflc/editdistance`

Comment: Thank you. I have found `python-Levenshtein` and it has method `distance()` which calculates the number of edits